# How to improve the influence of one element of the input on the latent code in an autoencoder?

Tags: feature-engineering, feature-extraction, autoencoder

I am trying to apply an autoencoder for feature extraction with the input like ***I=[x1,x2,x3,...,xn]***. Representing the latent code after encoding as ***L***, I want to improve the influence of one element of the input, such as ***x1***, on ***L***. My intention is that when ***x2,x3,...,xn*** remain constant, a small change in ***x1*** can lead to a huge change in the code ***L***. So what kind of autoencoder structure should be adopted to achieve this purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a new term to the loss that enforces precisely what you said: compute a modified version of the batch adding a very small variation to the $x_1$ component, compute the distance $D$ between the latent code of the original batch and the variation and add a new term to the loss in the lines of $L_D = 1/D$.

To combine the original loss and the new term, you can add them together with a weight $L + \alpha L_D$. To determine $\alpha$, you can try with different values, ensuring that the gradients of each term are not too different in magnitude.

Comment: You could also add weights for the reconstruction of each individual feature